# Flutter: How to modularize Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: flutter, oop, dart, state

I've been looking through multiple tutorials about the bottom navigation bar. Every single tutorial puts the bottom navigation bar in the main flutter file, which I don't like. I'm trying to modularize the app and put the bottom navigation bar in a second file with getters and setters to change and monitor the current view in place, but it's not working for me. I've tried to create setters and getters in the app file to be accessed by the navigation bar to handle navigation like this:

```
class _AppState extends State<App> {
  int _selectedPage = 0;
  final _pages = [HomePage(), EventsPage(), ThrivePage(), AnnouncementsPage()];

  int get currentPage => this._selectedPage;

  set currentPage(int thePage) {
    this._selectedPage = thePage;
  }
```

and the bottom navigation widget file would access it, but there's no actual variable for the App class so I can't access the class getters and setters.

I'm pretty new to OOP so there may be an approach I'm not familiar with. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What kind of layout do you want? Explain it properly.

Comment: I want a layout where there is a bottom navigation bar in the app. When I press on an icon, the app page changes, and the bottom navigation bar changes to highlight that you're on a specific view.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you want to hear now but you could create a custom tab and use a pageview as your views then use the pageview controller to change between screens now the custom navigation can be any file you just have to link them correctly.
I think I might write an article to really explain what I have said

Comment: Please do. An article would be great!  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ValueNotifier` to pass value between different widget. Make your bottom navigation class to take a ValueNotifier in constructor and add a listener to it.

```
class MyBottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<int> currentPageNotifier;


  MyBottomNavigationBar(this.currentPageNotifier);

  @override
  _MyBottomNavigationBarState createState() => _MyBottomNavigationBarState();
}

class _MyBottomNavigationBarState extends State<MyBottomNavigationBar> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.currentPageNotifier.addListener(() {
      print(widget.currentPageNotifier.value);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

From `_AppState` pass a ValueNotifier to `MyBottomNavigationBar` instance, then you can use that ValueNotifier to pass page index value to `MyBottomNavigationBar`

```
class _AppState extends State<App> {
  ValueNotifier<int> _currentPageNotifier = ValueNotifier(0);
  int _selectedPage = 0;

  int get currentPage => this._selectedPage;

  set currentPage(int thePage) {
    this._selectedPage = thePage;
    this._currentPageNotifier.value = thePage;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'You have pushed the button this many times:',
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomNavigationBar(_currentPageNotifier),// This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it fixes half of the problem. I'm also trying to send the index of the bottom navigation bar back to the _AppState class so the actual page changes when I press on a bottom navigation bar icon

Comment: I think you can also send the index of the bottom navigator using 
the same  changenotifier and listen from _AppState.